# Why is the default tab size 8 spaces? Where does this come from and why is it that big?

Tags: vim, microsoft-office, tabs, special-characters, characters

When I push `tab` in many applications like `vim`, OpenOffice etc., the tab size is equivalent to 8 spaces/characters.

This is the default for many applications. When the default terminal size is 80 chars horizontally, why is the tab size this big? After 5 tabs I am half way across the terminal, and text starts to look ugly, with text wrapping.

I was wondering what the history behind the decision for 8 chars tabs is.

I know how to change the settings in [vim to make it 4 chars](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces). I just want to understand why we still have 8 set as the default across so many applications.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article on "[Tab key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key)":

> In practice, settable tab stops were rather quickly replaced with
>   fixed tab stops, de facto standardized at every multiple of 8
>   characters horizontally, and every 6 lines vertically (typically one
>   inch vertically). A printing program could easily send the necessary
>   spaces or line feeds to move to any position wanted on a form, and
>   this was far more reliable than the modal and non-standard methods of
>   setting tab stops. Tab characters simply became a form of data
>   compression.
>
> It is unclear why the 8-character horizontal tab size was chosen,
>   since 5 characters, a half inch in a typical printer at that time, was
>   much more popular as a paragraph indentation.

Comment: Did not think it has some thing to do with an inch at all.

Comment: Why do we still keep that default.

Comment: @nelaar: Historical precedent; there are a lot of text files written to depend on 8-column tabstops.  But I (and a lot of other people) prefer spaces rather than tabs for indentation.  In my `.vimrc`, I have `set expandtab` and `set sw=4`; I keep tapstops (`ts`) set to the default 8.  I use Ctl-T and Ctrl-D for indentation.

Comment: Actually, I believe this comes from the days of manual typewriters - where a fixed tab stop every 8 characters allowed you to quickly format a table of numbers. 8 spaces allowed up to 7 characters plus a space; for most purposes that was (and is) sufficient. Any smaller and you can't fit your numbers; bigger, and you can't have very many columns in your table. I still have a manual typewriter that has fixed tab stops at every 8 characters.

Comment: Fyi, Wikipedia has modified that last paragraph to explain why 8 characters was chosen over 5 characters: "A common horizontal tab size of eight characters evolved, despite five characters being half an inch and the typical paragraph indentation of the time, because as a power of two it was easier to calculate in binary for the limited digital electronics available."